# User cannot change his password

Tags: windows-7, windows, passwords, user-accounts, active-directory

User is trying to change his password yet he will get the Error:

Unable to change password. New password does not match complexity and minimum length.

I tried him on different computers and faced the same issue. 
I used his proposed password to change mine and I was successful.

Comment: Have the user request assistance from the AD Administrator.  If the password was used before that’s likely the reason it’s not being allowed.  Since you never used the password you were allowed to use it.

Comment: I have used my password for him (to change his password) but still got the same error.

Comment: As an Administrator Forcefully reset his password and call it a day.  Different Password complexity rules can applied to different user groups

Answer (score 3):

See the “Passwords must meet complexity requirements” policy.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc786468(v=ws.10).aspx

Consider there are several factors that prevent the user from using a certain password.

Including they can’t have parts of their username or name in it.